# Using matplotlib animation with arrays as input

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making an interactive Partial Differential Equation Solver in python (I could draw or modify the field  in any moment).

The Solver and Analizer is ready. I only need the visualization. I took an example code and I did this toy code. which can animate data and modify it with the mouse movement

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.animation as animation

dx = 0.1
X=arange(0,10,dx)

#function to plot
Y = sin(pi*X)
pause = False
#a artificial simulation, the field is move rigidly
def simData():
    global Y
    t_max = 10000
    for t in range(t_max):
        if not pause:
            Y = roll(Y,1)
        yield Y

#detect the position when mouse click and fix the field at this position
def on_click(event):
    global pause,Y,movement
    pause = True
    index = int(event.xdata/dx)
    Y[index] =  event.ydata

#
def on_release(event):
    global pause
    pause = False

#detect the position when mouse is moving and is clicked and fix the field at this position
def on_move(event):
   global pause
   if pause:
    index = int(event.xdata/0.1)
    Y[index] =  event.ydata

def simPoints(simData):
    x = simData
    line.set_ydata(x)
    return line

#initial plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot(X, Y, 'b', ms=10) 
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)

#conecting the events
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', on_release)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)

#starting the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=False, interval=10,
    repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

But, the function animation need a generator with the data, I can't use an external function generating the data independly of the animation (I need to turn off the animation with the simulation still running). How can I do that?

(the structure I need for the simulations of a field U(X) is something like:

```
...
for t in steps:
  U = equation.integrate(U,t)
  if i_want_to_calculate: calculing_important_values(U)
  if i_want_to_visualize: screen.animate(U)
finishing_the_simulation()
```

Thanks!!! (and excuse my english)

Comment: It depends on how fast is `equation.integrate(U,t)`. For example if you can calculate 100 frames every second, and an animation only need 20 frames per second. Then you can make a multi process application, one process do the simulation and send data to an other process to show the animation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is the idea, but animation.FuncAnimation use a generator to do the animation, but, I want only use an array as input, and make the animation updating the screen. 

animation.FuncAnimation needs all the frames generated after of its call, I need to pass the frames one by one.